# Css Style change with JSF Validation

Tags: css, jsf

I am working on a requirement to highlight fields that have failed in red after JSF server side validation. No javascript can be used for validation. Is there a method to link server side validation with css style changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with a managed bean:

```
public class ValidBean {

  private UIComponent myComponent;

  public UIComponent getMyComponent() {
    return myComponent;
  }

  public void setMyComponent(UIComponent myComponent) {
    this.myComponent = myComponent;
  }

  public String getErrorStyle() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext
        .getCurrentInstance();
    String clientId = myComponent.getClientId(context);
    Iterator<FacesMessage> messages = context
        .getMessages(clientId);
    while (messages.hasNext()) {
      if (messages.next().getSeverity().compareTo(
          FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR) >= 0) {
        return "background-color: red";
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Request scope variable:

```
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>validBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>stylevalid.ValidBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
```

Sample view:

```
  <f:view>
    <h:form>
      <h:inputText binding="#{validBean.myComponent}" styleClass="foo"
        style="#{validBean.errorStyle}">
        <f:validateLength minimum="6" />
      </h:inputText>
      <h:commandButton />
      <h:messages />
    </h:form>
  </f:view>
```

The component is bound to the backing bean. If error messages have been queued for the component, it overrides its CSS class settings with its style attribute.

Comment: Hi this method looks good and works also but is injecting css styles from beans into jsp a standard practice is JSF. I mean from maintenance perspective its will entirely obvious that the change has to be made in Java classes. And if I want to add another style element it wont be possible. Its not a factor for me right now but I was just worried about any future problems.

Comment: Probably a slightly better alternative would be to dynamically determine the styleClass attribute. That way you would only need to change the CSS file rather than the Java class.

Comment: @Barun - you are correct; it is not an ideal solution. The core components tend to be a bit basic. Folk look to the control libraries for a richer experience. An alternative would be to make errorStyle a boolean and resolve the style value via a function: #{myfn:resolve(validBean.errorStyle, 'szErrStyle', 'szOkStyle')}. That way, you get fewer presentation layer details leaking into the back end.

Comment: @Drew - I'm not sure putting the CSS class names into the beans is any better than explicit styling. It could certainly be done, though.

Comment: @McDowell I would think it would be a little bit better because it still keeps all the styling rules in the CSS file. I can change all the red text to blue text by editing just the CSS file. On the other hand, I'd have to edit a collection of java files if I had a fair number of things like this I had to do. Neither are really ideal though because you're still tying the markup to the code pretty significantly.

Answer (score 1):

The seam framework makes this very easy. Check this out: http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/seam/Seam_Reference_Guide/JSF_form_validation_in_Seam.html

Comment: Hi this method looks good but we are not using seam in the current project...a pity though because as Seam constructs really help out in many cases..

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Seam is really a killer app for JSF. I can sympathize, however, as I'm working on a JSF app now which doesn't use Seam and I'm finding maintaining state through pageflows annoying.

Comment: Same state here...problems concerned with maintaining state...we are going with Spring Webflow...but thats for another topic..

Comment: Yeah. I unfortunately have a home-rolled system that isn't too sweet but it works until we can get the code base to a point where we can begin refactoring.