# Check Null field validation by Custom validator

Tags: java, jsf-1.2

In my application I want to check null validation from `managebean` by `Customvalidator`.
I am using jsf1.2 & I have a `<h:inputText>` and a `submitButton` in a form , when I click submitButton leaving the `inputText` field empty , I want to generate a message from backing bean. One more thing I have also set attribute `validator` with a backing bean method named`#{manageBean.validateField}`. How I can implement this. Thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check for required fields, you can just use the `required` and `requiredMessage` attribute of the component.

```
<h:inputText id="fldName" value="#{managedBean.property}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter value..."/>
<h:message for="fldName"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Vrushank  for reply, But I have a requirement to change styleClass of row containing error component dynamically at runtime, so I want to check this validation from backing bean. How I can this from `backing bean`.

Comment: You mean to say by using validator attr, you want to change styleClass?

Comment: In that case, bind the input component to the view via `binding` attribute. See this answer for a better example with explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14457883/1055089