# button style when form is not valid

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i'm using jsf/primefaces, when a component of my form is not valid, it is surrounding with red border (his style is ui-state-error).
Some of component doesn't have ui-state-error behaviour by default so i'm using

```
<p:selectOneMenu styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'ui-state-error'}">
```

I'm trying to have a button with red border but "component.valid" doesn't work for p:commandButton. Do you have an idea please ?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452594/how-to-change-css-class-for-the-inputfield-and-label-when-validation-fails Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using binding on hidden input text and that seems to be working